# Please help. BTC has left Armory wallet and shows as gray, but says "Not in the blockchain yet"

Tags: transactions, armory

I sent 1.5BTC in the usual way from my Armory wallet, but the transaction shows in gray as if it is still pending. When I click more details it says "Not in the blockchain yet".  If I search for the transaction on blockchain.info, there is no transaction recorded against the wallet ID I was sending to. I've also tried to send another small transaction a few times for 0.01 and 0.1 BTC to see if that works, but now I just keep getting an error.

> The transaction that you just executed, does not appear to have been accepted by the Bitcoin network yet. This can happen for a variety of reasons.
>
> On some occasions the transaction actually will succeed and this message is displayed prematurely. To confirm whether the the transaction actually succeeded, you can try this direct link to blockchain.info:
>
> https://blockchain.info/tx/e7c8737734ddba96337f...
>
> If you do not see the transaction on that webpage within one minute, it failed and you should attempt to re-send it. If it does show up, then you do not need to do anything else -- it will show up in Armory as soon as it receives one confirmation.
>
> If the transaction did fail, it is likely because the fee is too low. Try again with a higher fee. If the problem persists, go to "Help" and select "Submit Bug Report". Or use "File" -> "Export Log File" and then attach it to a support ticket at https://bitcoinarmory.com/support

However, the link to the armory support page is no longer active.

**IN SUMMARY:** 
• The total amount in my wallet was reduced by 1.5001 BTC
• In the Armory transaction list, the 1.5001 BTC shows in gray as if it is still pending. 
• I am unable to send any more bitcoins.

What do I need to do to retrieve the 1.5001 BTC to my wallet? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Someone solved this for me on another site. Here is the solution if anyone else has the issue: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1445276.new#new

Answer (score 1):

The original questioner had a comment pointing to the solution, which I will reproduce here for completeness. TL;DR: A bug. Upgrade the software.

Details from https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1846233.0

> Update: 0.96.0 has been released. Update to that if you are still
>   experiencing this problem.
>
> Many of you may have noticed that with the Armory 0.95.1 and Bitcoin
>   Core 0.14.0, Armory tends to fail to broadcast transactions and give
>   the "Transaction timed out" and "Transaction broadcast failed" error
>   messages.
>
> The underlying issue that is causing this problem has been fixed for
>   Armory 0.96, which will be released soon. However, in the meantime,
>   downgrading to Bitcoin Core 0.13.2 will fix the issue. Once 0.96 is
>   released, you will be able to use Bitcoin Core 0.14.0 again.
>
> To downgrade to Bitcoin Core 0.13.2, just download the Bitcoin Core
>   0.13.2 binaries from https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.13.2/ and install them as you would normally install a new version of Bitcoin
>   Core. There is no need to redownload the blockchain nor reindex
>   Bitcoin Core's databases nor rebuild Armory's databases.
>
> Now for the technical details about the problem, for those of you who
>   care.
>
> I first noticed this issue back in December, but only very recently
>   have I nailed down why this problem cropped up in the first place.
>
> Bitcoin Core 0.14.0 merged a change back in December which changed how
>   Bitcoin P2P messages were being broadcast. Previously, the p2p message
>   header and the message payload were sent all at the same time using
>   the same kernel call. However, during their net refactor and cleanup,
>   this mechanism was changed to send the message header in one call, and
>   then the payload in a separate call. This is more robust and allows
>   for better code separation, but it also causes problems for Armory.
>
> The implementation in Armory 0.95.1 for receiving the p2p messages is
>   not able to handle that the two parts of a p2p message are essentially
>   sent separately. It interprets the message header as one p2p message,
>   and the message payload as another p2p message. This means that it is
>   incorrectly parsing the messages. The crux of the issue is that every
>   so often Armory will receive a ping message from Bitcoin Core. However
>   the payload of the ping message is only 8 bytes, but the message
>   header must be 24 bytes. When Armory interprets the ping payload as a
>   separate message, it will throw an exception because it thinks the
>   message is too short. This exception causes the data processing thread
>   to exit and disconnect from Bitcoin Core. Once it disconnects, it will
>   typically reconnect, but the reconnect does not always mean that it
>   will actually be receiving new blocks and transactions and actually
>   remaining up-to-date with the blockchain. Thus, because of this
>   disconnect, when you go to send some Bitcoin, it will fail to either
>   connect to Bitcoin Core or the reconnected connection is messed up and
>   the transaction broadcast times out or just fails entirely.